# Used in the ionic chrom.sockets.udp, 'sockets' of undefined

Tags: cordova, sockets, google-chrome, ionic-framework, udp

I installed the cordova plugin:
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

According to the official sample:

```
 chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function (socketInfo) {
    // The socket is created, now we can send some data
    var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
      '255.255.255.255', 9999, function (sendInfo) {
        console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
      });
  });
```

but Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined.

I print chrome object found no sockets

What reason be? Plugin  installation is not correct?

Comment: Where do you bind the socket in your code?

Comment: Uh, I have no binding sockets, just installed plugin is called directly, there is no use in plugin, I don't really know how to configure him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`According to the official sample:...`  Er no, that just doesn't sound right.  I think you missed a few lines of code there.  (Can you provide a link to that  sample?) For sockets, you are going to have to `create()`, `bind()`, `send()` Look at [tests.js here,](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp/blob/master/tests/tests.js) navigated from the link you provided.  I'm thinking this makes more sense:

```
self = this;  // obviously this is based on how you have the socket "class" defined in JS
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function (socketInfo) {
    // The socket is created...
    var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    // Setup a listener event handler 
    chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(self.onReceive);
    // Bind the socket
    chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, "0.0.0.0", 0, function(result) {
        if (result < 0) {
            console.log("Error binding socket.");
            return;
        }
        // send out a message
        chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
            '255.255.255.255', 9999, function (sendInfo) {
                console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
        }); 
        // reminder: 255.255.255.255:9999 is the message destination address
});
```

Do note: my response if based on my use of chrome.sockets.udp within other applications (and not on ionic stuff...)  Try this code, see if it works for you.  Note: `onReceive(data){..}` is a custom function I wrote to parse and use return data within my JavaScript "class".  Its not a standard, pre-existing function.

edit: In response to your comment `I already can create, but in when chrome.sockets.udp.send arrayBuffer need what format?`, here is my buffer_converter.js file

```
// ref:  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-chrome-apps/9781491905272/ch04.html
// See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574916/how-to-send-string-over-udp-using-javascript-on-chrome-app

// translate text string to Arrayed buffer
function text2ArrayBuffer(str /* String */ ) {
    var encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
    return encoder.encode(str).buffer;
}

// translate Arrayed buffer to text string
function arrayBuffer2Text(buffer /* ArrayBuffer */ ) {
    var dataView = new DataView(buffer);
    var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    return decoder.decode(dataView);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already can create, but in when chrome.sockets.udp.send arrayBuffer need what format?

Comment: Check my last edit.  Does that make it clear?  Is that useful to you or others?  Check out [Mozilla Developer Network to understand what an ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) is...

Comment: OK, I have received your answer, I will study the ArrayBuffer, really thank you very much, solve my problems :)